# Source a value from custom record field to a field in employee record

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to source a value from a custom record field (type: decimal) to a field in employee record(type: decimal). when the custom record is created. Is there any way I can implement this in workflow or should I go for the script?
If I choose the script which script I need to write?
Actually, I am new to script.so can anyone show me some sample?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very much like business logic, and thus shouldn't be done in a template... but, maybe you have no choice, so you can write a function like this:

```
<#--
   Returns if two sequences (Java List-s or Java arrays usually) are equal.
   Items at the same index must have common comparable type, and no item
   can be null, or else you may get an error!
-->
<#function sequencesEqual s1, s2>
  <#if s1?size != s2?size>
    <#return false>
  </#if>
  <#list s1 as i1>
    <#if i1 != s2[i1?index]>
      <#return false>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <#return true>
</#function>
```

Then you can do things like `<#if sequencesEqual(foo, bar)>...</#if>`.